# Detecting call duration in my App

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have app and it is running and at that time the call is comming and after sometime i cancel that call can i find the duration of Call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at CTCoreTelephony framework provided in iPhone sdk. It provides classes and methods to access call and carrier related information.