# iPhone call duration

Tags: iphone, ios, core-telephony

For our iPhone application, we would like to call a particular phone number, then fetch the total duration of that call after it has completed.  This is to manage the billing of that particular phone call.

How can we determine the duration of a call executed in this manner?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting call duration in my App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7021417/detecting-call-duration-in-my-app)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you can do this with CoreTelephony but this will only give you some guess work. You can't exactly time the call on the iPhone.

If I kill the app when calling the number there is no way for you to get the total time spend on the call. And CoreTelephony can only tell you that a call is started not wether your app started the call. Also you app will be suspended (Become inactive) when the call starts.
Also when the call is finished the user will have to start your app again since the user isn't automatically returned to your app.

After the call when the user presses the home button you apps gets background, thus you really can't keep track of the call.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you have any reference url or sample demo? So kindly give me ref url. So that, I can view it. Once again, thanks for your kind help. It will be helpful to me. Once I will success or get some help will mark this as answer.

Comment: Here is the documentation on CoreTelephony: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/#section=Frameworks&topic=CoreTelephony. The link includes a demo app, which you could extend to do some call time. But there is just now way to get the call time exactly.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reference. I have one query in that if you have find out. Suppose, I design the page such that there will be 0 to 9 number. and then doing calling like "tell:<number>". So when call will be outgoind. not incoming. right? And when user stops the call then how much time user has spend that we have to find out. Do you have any idea about it? Thanks for your all help so far.

Comment: You really can't tell, because your app has become inactive and what is the users kills your app? there is just no way to do it safely.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have used the demo code provided by apple. In that, I am come to know that, if user dial the code then "Dialing" will display in app and if some one call to user then "Incoming" will display in app. But I didn't found the work for "Connected" or "Disconnected". So that, if user "connect" the phone then I start the timer for call. And when "Disconnected" found then disable the timer. So that, I can get exact time for call duration. do you have idea?

Comment: You just can't. there is noway to do that with any accuracy.

Comment: so the apps in itune for call limit not give accuracy ?